# Connection between large deviation principle and weak convergence/

Tags: probability, weak-convergence, large-deviation-theory

What is the relationship between large deviation and weak convergence? Consider a sequence of random variables {X_n}, does the LDP of sample mean imply the the distribution of X_n converge? If so, what is the relation between LDP rate function and weak convergence rate?

Answer (score 0):

I think the answer is NO, since large deviation tells something about the deviation of size $n$, not $\sqrt{n}$ as required in weak convergence results(like CLT).